# Codeigniter Pagination deleted row ~ index shifting issue

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, conflict

I'm showing **50** records per page. If **30** records have been deleted *(or will not show for any other reasons)* 1st page end index will **80** right? But second page index will be created **50** from pagination. So records between 50-80 indexes are shown both 1st and 2nd page.

How can I achieve this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Feed the `$config['total_rows']` variable in your pagination config the actual rows you want to show in view and it will calculate automatically, In other words count the total rows what you want to show, change the function of counting.

Answer (score 0):

You must to recalculate current page based on max pages allowed after deletes:

Example, if your current page is $page, starting in 1:

```
$rowsByPage = 20;
$nrRows = ...count()...;
$maxPage = intval($nrRows / $rowsByPage) + 1;
```

then, adjust your page:

```
if($page > $maxPage) {
    $page = $maxPage;
}
```